# Json message parsing failing before my custom constraintvalidator in a spring boot service

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I need to validate my DTO bean having enum as a field, to achieve the same I followed some solutions provided over here, but The json deserialization fails even before reaching my custom validator.

Solutions provided here by the other developers.

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {EnumValueValidator.class})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({
  ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,
  ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
  ElementType.FIELD,
  ElementType.METHOD,
  ElementType.PARAMETER
})
public @interface EnumValue {
  public abstract String message() default "{validation.enum.message}";

  public abstract Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  public abstract Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

  public abstract Class<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>> enumClass();
}



import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class EnumValueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EnumValue, Object> {
  private Object[] enumValues;

  @Override
  public void initialize(final EnumValue annotation) {
    enumValues = annotation.enumClass().getEnumConstants();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(final Object value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (null != value) {
      String contextValue = value.toString();

      for (Object enumValue : enumValues) {
        if (enumValue.toString().equals(contextValue)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

And used it over my WidgetTypeAddOrUpdateDTO as

```
@EnumValue(enumClass = IsActive.class, message = "Only ACTIVE and NOT_ACTIVE accepted.")
  private IsActive isActive;
```

And my request method in controller is like:

```
 @PostMapping("/widget/type")
  public ResponseEntity<String> addWidgetTypes(
      @Validated @RequestBody ValidatorList<WidgetTypeAddOrUpdateDTO> widgetTypeDTOs) {
    widgetTypeService.add(widgetTypeDTOs.getValidatedList());
    return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/dashboard/admin/widget/type")).build();
  }
```

While passing the value of isActive like {"isActive":"xyz"} it should give error by my validator, instead control is not even reaching to it, although If I dont pass it altogether then I do get my error.

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.xyz.dashboardservice.common.IsActive` from String "xyz": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [NOT_ACTIVE, ACTIVE]
```

Comment: please post the controller and the request which caused error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For applying validation you need to use @Valid annotaion. You must be missing @Valid that's the reason your validations are not working.
For more info: https://spring.io/blog/2009/11/17/spring-3-type-conversion-and-validation/

Later on one more issue is there. 
In your DTO WidgetTypeAddOrUpdateDTO the enum value holder variable is of type IsActive which is an enum. When spring will populate/deserialize the DTO from JSON it will throw an exception in case of invalid enum value so you need to change it to String type. Once you change it to String then string can contain any text but your validation will bound and validation error will be produced if there is an invalid value.
For more info :
https://funofprograming.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/java-enum-validator/

Comment: Even though I am aware of the solution you are providing but I am really tired of dealing with this in enum way and hence will go with what you are saying. Thanks.